# how to display base64 encoded pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, base64, embed

I have to display base64 pdf in new tab. I am using below code

```
 var windo = window.open("", "");  
 var objbuilder = '';
 objbuilder += ('<embed width=\'100%\' height=\'100%\'  src="data:application/pdf;base64,');
 objbuilder += (fileData);
 objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" />');
 windo.document.write(objbuilder);
```

It is working in FireFox and not working in Chrome and IE. I even tried with  tag, but same output, working in FF but not in Chrome and IE.

I look into below JsFiddles, for which are working in FF but not in Chrome,

http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/

http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/1/

My Chrome version is : Version 54.0.2840.99 m

FireFox Version : 49.0.2

How can this be done?

Comment: In my case when I tried to display base 64 encoded pdf string in iframe, it displayed blank page. It is working properly only on Firefox. After spending a day to make it work I finally found cause of error. In my PDF document I embedded HTML code that is generated from text editor, when I removed those HTML codes it started working. I found code blocks that are causing this error but there is no logical meaning the cause of bug. It is too long to explain what kind of bug I had, but all I can say is that it is totally nonsense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It should work with Chrome you can use

`<iframe src="data:base64...">`

`<object data="data:base64...">`

I've faced the same issue with **IE**: it's **impossible** to display a pdf with a `base64` string.

I had to generate temporary files on the server to display them with **IE** he only **display existing file** by using a path.

You still can use **JS library** to display your pdf like `PDF.js`.

Comment: I tried Object and iframe also tried URIdata, but not working in Chrome
You can see below JSFiddles,

http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/

http://jsfiddle.net/yLx2W/1/

Comment: I've just copy and paste the code on Jsfiddle in a html file and launch it with Chrome, it works

Comment: Agree... It does not work on fiddle, but it works locally. I use the same code (the iframe one) but it does not work with my data. When it works with the example of @dnyaneshwar

Comment: How about large PDF files ? It's working with small pdf good, but no large pdf files.

Answer (score 29):

for those who still can't do it, i found this in someone else answer, but i don't remember who...

```
var objbuilder = '';
objbuilder += ('<object width="100%" height="100%" 
data="data:application/pdf;base64,');
objbuilder += (myBase64string);
objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" class="internal">');
objbuilder += ('<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,');
objbuilder += (myBase64string);
objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf"  />');
objbuilder += ('</object>');

var win = window.open("#","_blank");
var title = "my tab title";
win.document.write('<html><title>'+ title +'</title><body style="margin-top: 
0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">');
win.document.write(objbuilder);
win.document.write('</body></html>');
layer = jQuery(win.document);
```

this way we open the pdf in a new tab.

Comment: Thx. Your solution works great with PDFKIT from node.js

Comment: I have base64String data and need to open in mvc view using iframe control. I am trying to use embed and ifame but none of them working.     var pdfData = '@Model.PdfDataString';
    $("iframe").attr("src", 'data:application/pdf;base64,{0}'.replace('{0}', pdfData));
    $("embed").attr("src", 'data:application/pdf;base64,{0}'.replace('{0}', pdfData));

Comment: sorry, i'm not into MVC

Comment: @chaco it's not working for big pdfs in chrome. like this one https://jsfiddle.net/eqc3umab/

Comment: it allows up to 9 pages i guess

Comment: @chaco This is not wirking in IE

Comment: @GowriTumma sorry for not helping, in here IE is totally deprecated...

Answer (score 7):

When the above answer's do not work due to Size Limitations, you can try this solution, it worked for me when I was trying to convert 16+ page PDFs from Base64 back into a PDF in Chrome.

The fix is to convert the base64 back into Binary, pack it inside of a Blob, and then set the iframe's "src" to a Blob-URI pointing to that blob.

```js
var base64 = ("yourBase64StringVariable")
const blob = base64ToBlob( base64, 'application/pdf' );
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
const pdfWindow = window.open("");
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + url + "'></iframe>");

function base64ToBlob( base64, type = "application/octet-stream" ) {
  const binStr = atob( base64 );
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[ i ] = binStr.charCodeAt( i );
  }
  return new Blob( [ arr ], { type: type } );
}
```

Original Source of this answer - [Open base64 encoded pdf file using javascript. Issue with file size larger than 2 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488416/open-base64-encoded-pdf-file-using-javascript-issue-with-file-size-larger-than)

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. This the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
function printPreview(data){
        var type = 'application/pdf';
        let blob = null;
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL( pdfBlobConversion(data, 'application/pdf'));
        const theWindow = window.open(blobURL);
        const theDoc = theWindow.document;
        const theScript = document.createElement('script');
        function injectThis() {
            window.print();
        }
        theScript.innerHTML = 'window.onload = ${injectThis.toString()};';
        theDoc.body.appendChild(theScript);
    }
  //converts base64 to blob type for windows
    function pdfBlobConversion(b64Data, contentType) {
          contentType = contentType || '';
          var sliceSize = 512;
          b64Data = b64Data.replace(/^[^,]+,/, '');
          b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');
          var byteCharacters = window.atob(b64Data);
          var byteArrays = [];

          for ( var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset = offset + sliceSize ) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
              byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
          }

          var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
          return blob;
        }
```

pass base64 data to this function and it will show the pdf in new window. 
This is working in chrome and firefox not in IE.
Any help Please. I want it to work in IE also. 
Its giving error where I give the bloburl to window.

Answer (score 2):

Here '@Model.binaryDocument' is the base64 data

1)By Model

```
<object>
   <embed id="pdfID" type="text/html" width="1200" height="600" src="data:application/pdf;base64,@Model.binaryDocument" />
</object>
```

2)By js

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var b64Data = "@Model.binaryDocument";
    var contentType = "application/pdf";
     const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    (window as Window).location = blobUrl;
  })

const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) 
       {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
}
```

✔
**First solution is better for prevent auto downloading pdf.**