# opening a pdf file in modal possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i was thinking of opening a pdf file in modal . current using

```
@Html.ActionLink("open file", "Download")
```

open another windows. i want it to populate it to a div so that i can view in in modal or  overlay.

i am ok with jquery solution as well as currently my jquery return me some bytes character.

```
function openfile() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Download", "mycontroller")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/pdf",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#showpdf').html(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
           alert(err)
        }
    });
}
```

Action in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/pdf/service_reports/SR26175.pdf");
    return File(path, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: It's not possible into div, only another window or image

Comment: so can i put a `<img>` and put pdf inside a image and put that image in div?

Comment: lol - nope. You can transform your `PDF` into `IMG`, and IMG into `base64` data format, and then show inside `<img>`.

Comment: You can make use of [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for this purpose.

Comment: @anete.anetes lol. i do not know that haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is pass pdf path from json request and then use object inside the modal div:

```
<object id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="path/file.pdf"></object>
```

---

```
function openfile() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Download", "mycontroller")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#showpdf').html('<object id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="' + data.path +'"></object>');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/pdf/service_reports/SR26175.pdf");
    return Json(new {path = path});
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
For better user experience on different browsers that maybe doesn't support `object` tag, we could use `object` with `embed` tag as a fallback:

```
<object data="/path/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="700px" height="700px">
    <embed src="/path/file.pdf">
        This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/path/file.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: not working. ajax error return object object. I change the `dataType: "application/pdf",` to  `dataType: "application/json",` and `public JsonResult Download()` also same error

Comment: hardcoding works. But result same as iframe. mini size. 
`<object id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="@Url.Content(@"~/pdf/service_reports/SR26175.pdf")"></object>`

Comment: what you mean, "mini size"?

Comment: @MVCnewbie to change size you need to set <object> or iframe width and height

Comment: you are right. i set the width and height of the modal. But i didnt set the <object> thanks thanks

Comment: @anete.anetes depends on browser, it should work in chrome and firefox but not sure about safari

Comment: added note about fallback for browsers that doesn't support `object` tag

Comment: how to use this if pdf file is not on server but in bytes as base64?

Comment: @newdeveloper  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674532/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf maybe it would help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a controller named home. You can use an iframe like this

```
<div id='yourModel'>
   <iframe src="/Home/Download"></iframe>
</div>
```

and use jQuery to show / hide the div.

Comment: simple and works. But the result not very nice. pdf too small to view. if no choice then i will adopt new window.thanks

Comment: you can always use width and height to adjust the width and height of your iframe to meet your needs

Comment: yea.adjust as show in picture. the pdf is in the middle which is very small also.

Comment: I have tried it and showing better result. try this
<iframe src="/Home/Download" width="100%" height="800px;"></iframe>

Comment: yes i also tried that. just now i increase my div and modal but not iframe thats why. thanks buddy

Comment: it's a pleasure when it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've trying this but at the end I've made this becacuse I need to show diferent pdfs, that are stored (just the full path) in a DB and on a shared folder, then I have to show it one by one to the user, well hope it works for you!

on the view inner the modal body.

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                <object id="pdfViewer" data="~/Evidence/PdfFile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="790" height="500"></object>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <label id="errorTxt"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

on the controller in a jsonresult.

```
            //HERE I GET THE REAL PATH OF THE FILE
            string evidence = _manager.GetEvidence(id);

            //CREATING THE NEW PATH FOR THE FILE
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Evidence/"), "PdfFile.pdf");

            //SAVE TEMPORARILY ON EVIDENCE FOLDER INNER THE PROYECT
            //WITH THE NEW NAME 
            System.IO.File.Copy(evidence, path, true);

            //AND JUST RETURN A JSON WITH A MESSAGE TO OPEN MODAL
            return Json("OK",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and the js function with jquery

```
function ShowExistEvidence(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetEvidence","ControllerName")",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === 'OK') {                    
                $("#modViewEvidencia").modal("show");
            } else {
               $("#errorTxt").text('File not found');
               $("#modViewEvidencia").modal("show");
            }

        }
    });
}
```