# Form with File- Upload to Json- String to JavaBackend

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, forms

I have an html form which i parse to json and send it to my java- backend.

```
        var data = {};
        var formArray = $("#form").serializeArray();
        $.each(formArray, function (i, field) {
            if(field.name !== '') {
                data[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: encodedContextPath + "/form/send",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json'
            ........
```

Now i need to add the ability to also upload a pdf file, how can i put this file into my json which i'll send to the backend?
Can i serialize it somehow or generate a data stream which i can put into the json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdf file upload ajax html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileReader to get the data of pdf file and send it in json.

```
let pdfFile;
$('<file-input-id-or-class>').on('change', onPdfUpload);

function onPdfUpload($event) {
    let file = $event.target.files[0];
    if (!file) return;

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        pdfFile = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}


var data = {};
    var formArray = $("#form").serializeArray();
    $.each(formArray, function (i, field) {
        if(field.name !== '') {
            data[field.name] = field.value;
        }
    });

   data.pdfFileContent = pdfFile;// you can change field name accordingly

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: encodedContextPath + "/form/send",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
```

Comment: I managed to send the file to my backend but now im struggling getting back the data from the base64 String

Comment: For displaying PDF from Base64, you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674532/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf