# base64encoded pdf is not working in html page

Tags: base64url

I would like to open a pdf in my html page. I am using following sample php code for this

```
<?
         $a= base64_encode("test");
         $url=' <object  type="application/pdf" data="data:application/pdf;base64,'.$a.'" width="800" height="800">No Support  </object>';
         echo $url;
        ?>
```

When we are running this code, got error:

> Failed to load PDF document

Am I missing anything this code?

Answer (score 0):

visit this link 
[how to display base64 encoded pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674532/how-to-display-base64-encoded-pdf)
it's impossible to display a pdf with a base64 string.