# Opening base64 pdf in a new tab freezes tab over some file size

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

We are using this approach to open the content of a PDF document in another tab

```
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;' + someDoc.url + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

However it seems that over some size the tab freezes and stays in continue loading. 
I have tried also with 5MB documents.

Is there any better approach to avoid this problem.

Browser used: Google Chrome 80.0.3987.122 or Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR)

Comment: Some browsers only support data URLs up to some size limit, probably 2 MB.

Comment: @mkl this limit only applies to the address bar url, you can very well load bigger files from a dataURI: https://jsfiddle.net/nbfdakor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your pdf from a blob:URI instead of from a data:URI.

```
var win = window.open();
var blob = base64ToBlob(someDoc.url, 'application/pdf');
win.document.write('<iframe src="' + URL.createObjectURL( blob ) + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')


function base64ToBlob( base64, type = "application/octet-stream" ) {
  const binStr = atob( base64 );
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[ i ] = binStr.charCodeAt( i );
  }
  return new Blob( [ arr ], { type: type } );
}
```

[live plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fTB39JwOXYtHvmEtElB0?p=preview)

There are bugs in Chrome's plugin and Firefox's *pdf.js*, I also experienced this problem while writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488416/open-base64-encoded-pdf-file-using-javascript-issue-with-file-size-larger-than/60256297#60256297) on a very related question <sub>(which doesn't have an accepted answer and can't be used as dupe target)</sub>.