# base64 embeded PDF files won't render in Chrome

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, base64, embed

Some PDF files won't render in Chrome browser but will render fine in Firefox. All files render fine in all browsers if emeded directly.

```
<object id="content-view" :data="content_view.base64" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

The confusing part is that the problem is only for some files and not all. Files are stored in a folder that is not public and that's why they are served as base64 for the user to view.

[image: screenshot]

I tested the problematic files by using online base64 decoders and I get the same result. Rendered in FF, not rendered in Chrome.

I cannot share any of the PDF files. They are all from the same source, scanned from the same device, PDF version 1.4, 4 pages.

I have tried:

- using iframe, embed and object (same result)
- unblocking *Insecure content* in Chrome site settings
- opening and re-saving in Adobe Acrobat
- using online PDF analyzers to see if any problems present (none found)

Comment: This could very well be a bug in chrome, perhaps you should submit a bug report

Comment: use pdf.js, i have used it on my website to render pdf's in a canvas on my webpage

Comment: I have the same problem. This is very annoying, in FF it opens fine.

Comment: Hello just wondering if anyone found a solution to this working in chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I noticed that some of the PDFs that are more than 1MB isn't loading.

I found a solution here: [Open base64 encoded pdf file using javascript. Issue with file size larger than 2 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488416/open-base64-encoded-pdf-file-using-javascript-issue-with-file-size-larger-than)

Need to change the Base64 string to a BLOB. Then create a URL to be used for iframe src.

Here is the code:

```
base64PDFToBlobUrl( base64 ) {
  const binStr = atob( base64 );
  const len = binStr.length;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[ i ] = binStr.charCodeAt( i );
  }
  const blob =  new Blob( [ arr ], { type: 'application/pdf' } );
  const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
  return url;
}
```

This will return a url that you can put inside your iframe, embed or object src. This way, you can still load the PDF in a page without opening it in another tab.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the browsers native PDF renderer, you could use the JS one written by Mozilla.

[ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/) provides a nice interface to this and if you want to embed it fullsize in a page, then you can place it in an iframe and control that with [iFrame-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the PDF file in HTML object element, open it in a new window using Blob URL.

Please refer

[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

to convert Base64 to Blob